# Replace if number statements with text

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to complete this assignment where if an integer is divisible by 2,3, and 7, it replaces the following numbers (25-50) with "BuzzLightYear"

I have the numbers listed correctly, but when I run the program it prints the text along with the number when I just want the text instead of the number.

Here is my code:

```
int variable = 25;

while (variable <= 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine(variable + "\n");
    ++variable;
    if (variable % 2 == 0 && variable % 3 == 0 && variable % 7 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("BuzzLightYear");

    }

}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: just use if condition and don't print  Console.WriteLine(variable + "\n");

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(variable + "\n");` is always going to print the variable.  You need an `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int variable = 25;

while (variable <= 50)
{
    if (variable % 2 == 0 && variable % 3 == 0 && variable % 7 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("BuzzLightYear\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(variable + "\n");
    }
    ++variable;
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int variable = 25;
    
            while (variable <= 50)
            {
                
                if (variable % 2 == 0 && variable % 3 == 0 && variable % 7 == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("BuzzLightYear");
    
                }
               else{
                       Console.WriteLine(variable + "\n");
                 }
                 ++variable;
            }
                Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're always printing the number. Just put that in an `else` instead.

But anytime you need a set number of iterations, a `for` loop is generally better because the loop variable declaration, condition, and increment are all in one place:

```
for (int variable = 25; variable <= 50; variable++)
{
    if (variable % 2 == 0 && variable % 3 == 0 && variable % 7 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BuzzLightYear");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(variable);
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```